# Empty_add rotation not working when adding picture?

Tags: python

So im trying to write a simple script that adds a reference image and rotates it 90 degrees on the X axis.

When an image is added thru script it will not rotate the object.

```
import bpy
from math import pi

bpy.ops.object.empty_add(type='IMAGE', radius=0.1, location=(0, 0, 0), rotation=((pi * 90 / 180), 0, 0), scale=(1, 1, 1))
bpy.ops.object.load_reference_image(filepath="C:\\front.jpg")
```

However, If I remove the line of time image, it rotates. Why is that and how can I fix it?

```
import bpy
from math import pi

bpy.ops.object.empty_add(type='IMAGE', radius=0.1, location=(0, 0, 0), rotation=((pi * 90 / 180), 0, 0), scale=(1, 1, 1))
```

Comment: don't know why, scripting with operators is not always reliable, but you could rotate it after loading image, something like bpy.context.object.rotation_euler=((pi * 90 / 180), 0, 0)

Comment: @alambre yes thank you, I was aware just wanted to make the code more compact and add the rotation while it's added. But I guess that's impossible? Bug perhaps?